# javascript equivalent of jquery for this function

Tags: javascript

In a dinamically generated "ol" :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('ol');
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
          var newLi = document.createElement("li");
          var link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = "#"; 
          link.innerHTML = (results.rows.item(i).location + "-" + results.rows.item(i).datte);
          newLi.appendChild(link);
          olnew[0].appendChild(newLi);
```

i need find the "li" clicked, i use jquery library only for this function, i am searching for the same functionality in javascript, but at momento i have not idea how i can code it. thx
    var ss;
    ss=$("#idfromOl");
    ss.click(clickhecho);

```
}

function clickhecho()
{
    var $all_lis = $('li');

    $all_lis.on('click', function() {
        var index = $all_lis.index(this);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function createfunc(i) {
    return function() { alert(i); };
}
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
    var newLi = document.createElement("li");
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = "#"; 
    link.innerHTML ="test"
    newLi.appendChild(link);
    // just add onclick event; use createFunc to create function closure (otherwise 'i' would always be the last 'i'
    newLi.onclick = createfunc(i);

    olnew[0].appendChild(newLi);
}
```

Comment: it work fine, thx. not sense use a jquery library for 4 lines of javascript

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but is this what you are looking for?

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        $("#clickedLi").text(e.srcElement.id);
    });
}
```

It appends an event called `addEventListener` to every `li` element.

Inside each `li` element there is an `click` event given as a parameter which contains the `id` of the `li` clicked.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DUzMc/1/

Comment: It seems user2764662 is trying to avoid jquery.

Comment: It's not jquery, exept for the `text()` function, but thats not what he'll use, his question was how to determine which `li` was clicked using nothing but javascript. The `text()` is only used to display the `id` into an textbox which is created into the example.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to include the event while generating the list:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('ol');
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
      var newLi = document.createElement("li");
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = "#"; 
      link.innerHTML = (results.rows.item(i).location + "-" + results.rows.item(i).datte);

      // Add this
      link.onclick = function(index) { return function() {
        // do something with index variable
      }}(i);

      newLi.appendChild(link);
      olnew[0].appendChild(newLi);
```

Note I use a local variable index instead of i, this is because when the item is clicked the value of i will be different (equal to len).

Comment: Will not work because of closure issue: 'i' would always be the same (last loop value).

Answer (score 0):

Your first part of script is incomplete, so I did a short script to generate a dynamic list.

Basicly you were looking for [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

```
var elements = 10;
ol = document.createElement('ol');
for(i = 1; i <= elements; i++){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', '#');
    a.text = 'Link ' + i;
    li.appendChild(a);
    ol.appendChild(li);

    a.addEventListener("click", who, false); // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
}

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(ol);


function who(e){
    var myTarget = e.target;
    myTarget.text = "clicked!";
}
```